# OpenGL Core Profile: Moving bricks separately

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Thanks for reading it. I am a fresh to OpenGl Core Profile and stuck at this problem following:

---

**Discription:**

I want to draw a group of bricks and move them separately with a speed and if they touch the border or each other they will turn around. So I decided to do a start demo but no soon I found I can not set the location of bricks separately:

- Only when I use `glm::translate(model, translatePOS[i] * (float)glfwGetTime())` can I change all the bricks. But I meant to change the displacement none-linearly. Not like `time * speed`, but like `Displacement_Function(time)`.
- When I use `glm::translate(model, translatePOS[i]+  x[i] * xUnit[i] + y[i] * yUnit[i] + z[i] * zUnit[i])`, what I observed is only one brick will moving around in the space.

---

**Question:**

- Why there is only one brick moving around? How could I fix this?
- Is only `(float)glfwGetTime()` related character can update all the positions?
- What't the standard way to set and change more than one objects with OpenGL core profile?

---

And I really need someone's help to figure it out. I would appreciate it so much if you could give me a clue what's going wrong behind it, sincerely!

My code is running in this environment and using these libs and APIs:

> Windows 10 enterprise
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
>
> OpenGL (higher than 3.3)
>
> glfw
>
> glad
>
> "shader_m.h"(download from [shader_m.h file](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h)) by Sean Barrett

---

The whole code is here(modified from the free tutorial at [learnopengl website](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures)):

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "shader_m.h"

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

                                                         // glfw window creation
                                                         // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader ourShader("DX.vs", "PX.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    // world space positions of our cubes
    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
        glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1, texture2;
    // texture 1
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("textures/t1.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    // texture 2
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    data = stbi_load("textures/s4.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ourShader.use();
    ourShader.setInt("texture1", 0);
    ourShader.setInt("texture2", 1);


    // render loop
    // -----------
#define BrickNUM 100
    glm::vec3 translatePOS[BrickNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        float Lx = -1.0;
        float Hx = 1.0;
        float Ly = -1.0;
        float Hy = 1.0;
        float Lz = -20.0;
        float Hz = -30.0;
        float r1 = Lx + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hx - Lx)));
        float r2 = Ly + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hy - Ly)));
        float r3 = Lz + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hz - Lz)));
        translatePOS[i].x = r1;
        translatePOS[i].y = r2;
        translatePOS[i].z = r3;
        std::cout << "(" << translatePOS[i].x << "," << translatePOS[i].y << "," << translatePOS[i].z << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    glm::vec3 velocity[BrickNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        float Lx = -0.1;
        float Hx = 0.1;
        float Ly = -0.1;
        float Hy = 0.1;
        float Lz = -0.1;
        float Hz = 0.1;
        float r1 = Lx + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hx - Lx)));
        float r2 = Ly + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hy - Ly)));
        float r3 = Lz + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hz - Lz)));
        velocity[i] = glm::vec3(r1, r2, r3);
    }
    float velocityFloat[BrickNUM][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        float Lx = -0.1;
        float Hx = 0.1;
        float Ly = -0.1;
        float Hy = 0.1;
        float Lz = -0.1;
        float Hz = 0.1;
        float r1 = Lx + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hx - Lx)));
        float r2 = Ly + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hy - Ly)));
        float r3 = Lz + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hz - Lz)));
        velocityFloat[i][0] = 10.0*r1;
        velocityFloat[i][1] = 10.0*r2;
        velocityFloat[i][2] = 10.0*r3;
    }
    glm::vec3 rotateDEC[BrickNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        float Lx = 0.0;
        float Hx = 1.0;
        float Ly = 0.0;
        float Hy = 1.0;
        float Lz = 0.0;
        float Hz = 1.0;
        float r1 = Lx + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hx - Lx)));
        float r2 = Ly + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hy - Ly)));
        float r3 = Lz + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hz - Lz)));
        rotateDEC[i] = glm::vec3(r1, r2, r3);
    }
    glm::vec3 test= glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    float x[BrickNUM];
    float y[BrickNUM];
    float z[BrickNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        x[i] = translatePOS[i].x;
        y[i] = translatePOS[i].y;
        z[i] = translatePOS[i].z;
    }
    glm::vec3 xUnit[BrickNUM];
    glm::vec3 yUnit[BrickNUM];
    glm::vec3 zUnit[BrickNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < BrickNUM; i++) {
        float Lx = 0.0;
        float Hx = 1.0;
        float Ly = 0.0;
        float Hy = 1.0;
        float Lz = 0.0;
        float Hz = 1.0;
        float r1 = Lx + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hx - Lx)));
        float r2 = Ly + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hy - Ly)));
        float r3 = Lz + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (Hz - Lz)));
        xUnit[i] = glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        yUnit[i] = glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        zUnit[i] = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    }
    float timeLast = (float)glfwGetTime();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // also clear the depth buffer now!

                                                            // bind textures on corresponding texture units
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        // activate shader
        ourShader.use();

        // create transformations
        glm::mat4 view;
        glm::mat4 projection;
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        // pass transformation matrices to the shader
        ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection); // note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice to set it outside the main loop only once.
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);

        // render boxes





        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // calculate the model matrix for each object and pass it to shader before drawing
            glm::mat4 model;
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            float timeNow = (float)glfwGetTime();
            //std::cout << timeNow << std::endl;
            if (1) {
                x[i] += (timeNow - timeLast) *  velocityFloat[i][0];
                y[i] += (timeNow - timeLast) *  velocityFloat[i][1];
                z[i] += (timeNow - timeLast) *  velocityFloat[i][2];
                std::cout << "(" << x[i] << "," << y[i] << "," << z[i] << ")" << std::endl;
                timeLast = timeNow;
                if (x[i] > 10.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][0] = -velocityFloat[i][0];
                }
                if (y[i] > 10.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][1] = -velocityFloat[i][1];
                }
                if (z[i] < -90.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][2] = -velocityFloat[i][2];
                }
                if (x[i] < -10.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][0] = -velocityFloat[i][0];
                }
                if (y[i] < -10.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][1] = -velocityFloat[i][1];
                }
                if (z[i] > -1.0) {
                    velocityFloat[i][2] = -velocityFloat[i][2];
                }
            }
            //glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            float xx = x[i];
            float yy = y[i];
            float zz = z[i];
            glm::vec3 tmp3;
            tmp3.x = translatePOS[i].x + xx * xUnit[i].x;
            tmp3.y = translatePOS[i].y + yy * yUnit[i].y;
            tmp3.z = translatePOS[i].z + zz * zUnit[i].z;
            glm::vec3 tmp4 = glm::vec3((translatePOS[i].x + xx * xUnit[i].x), (translatePOS[i].y + yy * yUnit[i].y), (translatePOS[i].z + zz * zUnit[i].z));
            float testTime = (float)glfwGetTime() + xx;
            //model = glm::translate(model, tmp4);
            //model = glm::translate(model, testTime * zUnit[i]);
            //model = glm::translate(model, translatePOS[i]+  x[i] * xUnit[i] + y[i] * yUnit[i] + z[i] * zUnit[i]);
            model = glm::translate(model, translatePOS[i] + x[i] * xUnit[i]);
            float angle = 20.0f * i;
            model = glm::rotate(model, timeNow* glm::radians(angle) / 10, rotateDEC[i]);
            ourShader.setMat4("model", model);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }
        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: You should specify if you are using OpenGL or OpenGL ES and adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I changed it. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Your actual question is not clear to me. Also, please see these [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sure I will rearrange it as soon as I can! Thanks.